# Profiling http connections

Tags: http, erlang

I try to find a way for profiling http/https connections made by my Erlang app.

I need to know how long it takes to make a connection to a web server, to send a request to a web server, to get first info from a web server (aka the time needed by a web server to process request and prepare the answer) and the time of receiving an the whole answer from a web server.

**What the easiest way to do it? Maybe you know a client which can be easily modified for gathering this information?**

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark has several HTTP analysis tools built-in.

Comment: I have to have it implemented in my Erlang app which connects to different web sites and should also gather profiling information about these connections. Using external programs is not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use some builtin profiles? http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html

Comment: It's not about profiling of algorithm of http connection it's about gathering some basic time consuming statistics of each internet connection and using this info for app-specific purposes e.g. switching to another web-site if some connection parameters exceed some boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

For low volume testing, I'd recommend using [firebug](http://testnscale.com/blog/performance/using-firebug-when-load-testing/) on Firefox or [Fiddler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250442.aspx).

For bulk monitoring, you might want to take a look at....

- [Yahoo Boomerang](http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2010/06/performance_testing_with_boomerang/)
- [Graphite](http://allanfeid.com/content/tracking-stats-your-application)
- [PasTmon](http://pastmon.sourceforge.net/Wikka-1.1.6.5/wikka.php?wakka=HomePage)
- [Episodes](http://stevesouders.com/episodes/)
- [HTML5's Web Timing API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/NavigationTiming/Overview.html)